# iOS Autolayout resize labels and space between them

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uilabel, autolayout

I'm using Autolayout on iOS 7 to design my views.
I can resize my view automatically, and all my objects, but I have a problem:
I have 4 labels one next to the other. These labels are in a UIView, and when my UIView is resizing (width), I would like my labels move automatically like but still visible.

Here is the thing:
[image]

And when the UIView is resizing:
[image]

You know what I mean ? I fixed the right label on the right side of the view. It works.
For the first label, it's not a problem.
But for the label 2 and 3, I don't know how to adapt the minimum space between them.

All suggestions and idea are well appreciate. Thank you.

Regards, 
Lapinou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this UIView category: https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

You could achieve this really easily...

```
NSArray *views = @[ button1, button2, button3, button4 ];
[self.containerView spaceViews:views onAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal withSpacing:10 alignmentOptions:0];
```

Edit: Actually... This makes the width of each button dynamic and might not meet your needs exactly.

Comment: Awesome! This project is really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to work with `Equal Widths` constraint and stick the left button to the left side and same for the right button and finally a `Horizontal Space Constraint` for every button equal to 0.

That should work...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the constant property on an NSLayoutConstraint object manually inside -viewDidLayoutSubviews. I'm assuming the labels don't have a fixed width so they won't all have a constant space between each other. It looks like you want them in quadrants of each other which the first and last labels having a fixed distance from the edge. Perhaps labels 2 and 3 can be centered horizontally to the container, and then be offset by the container's width/2.

```
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.label2
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.view
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:self.view.frame.size.width/2.0];
```

label2 would have a constant like posted above, but label 3 would have this constant as a negative value.